# Calculating the $M_X(t)$ of the pdf $f_X(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{2}$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, moment-generating-function

I am working on calculating the moment generating function for the  pdf $f_X(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{2}$ with the bounds $[0, \pi]$, and here is my attempt although I would like to know whether I have approached this correctly.

Using the moment generating function for a continuous pdf:

$\int e^{tx}f_X(x)dx$

Then I have:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi e^{tx}\sin(x)dx$$

Then using integration by parts via substitituion:
$u = \sin(x)$ and $du = \cos(x)$, where $v = e^{tx}$ and $\frac{1}{t}dv = e^{tx}$

Putting this altogether:

$1. \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{t}\sin(x)e^{tx} |_0^\pi-\frac{1}{t}\int_0^\pi\cos(x)e^{tx} dx\right]$

The LHS becomes 0 when $x = 0$, and when $x = \pi$ it becomes 0 again as $\sin(\pi) = 0; \sin(0) = 0$

Then calculating the RHS:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[-\frac{1}{t^2}\cos(x)e^{tx}|_0^\pi-\frac{1}{t^2}\int_0^\pi\sin(x)e^{tx}dx \right]$$

Whenever we get $\sin(x)$ it's always going to be 0 relative to the bounds $[0, \pi]$ although, when we get cos, then we will get something like this:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{e^{t\pi}+1}{t^2} \right]$$

Because $\cos(\pi)=-1;\cos(0)=1$
From:
$\frac{1}{2}\left[-\frac{(-1)e^{t\pi}}{t^2}-(- \frac{(1)e^{t(0)}}{t^2}) \right]$

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+exp%28t*x%29*sin%28x%29%2F2+from+0+to+pi) provides a check- it seems to have a slightly different denominator so $\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{e^{t\pi}+1}{t^2+1} \right]$

Comment: The calculation is almost instantaneous when you express $\sin(x)$ as the imaginary part of $\exp(ix),$ for then you only need integrate $\exp(tx + ix)$ from $0$ to $\pi$ (and take the imaginary part of the result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,

$$M_X(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{tx}\frac{sin(x)}{2}dx}=\int_{0}^{\pi}{e^{tx}\frac{sin(x)}{2}dx}$$

Using integration by parts with $u'=e^{tx}, v=sin(x)$:

$$M_X(t)=\frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{1}{t}e^{tx}sin(x)-\int{\frac{1}{t}e^{tx}cos(x)} \right]_0^\pi$$

The left term does fall as you mentioned so:
$$M_X(t)=-\frac{1}{2t}\left[ \int{e^{tx}cos(x)} \right]_0^\pi$$

Again we integrate by parts, this time with $u'=e^{tx}, v=cos(x)$, recall that ${cos(x)}'=-sin(x)$:

$$M_X(t)=
-\frac{1}{2t}\left[ \frac{1}{t}e^{tx}cos(x)-\int{\frac{1}{t}e^{tx}\left(-sin(x)\right)} \right]_0^\pi=-\frac{1}{2t}\left[ \frac{1}{t}e^{tx}cos(x)+\int{\frac{1}{t}e^{tx}sin(x)} \right]_0^\pi
=
-\frac{1}{2t^2}\left[ e^{tx}cos(x) \right]_0^\pi-\frac{1}{2t^2}\left[ \int {e^{tx}sin(x)} \right]_0^\pi=
-\frac{1}{2t^2}\left[ e^{tx}cos(x) \right]_0^\pi-\frac{1}{t^2}\left[ \int {e^{tx}\frac{sin(x)}{2}} \right]_0^\pi=
-\frac{1}{2t^2}\left[ e^{tx}cos(x) \right]_0^\pi-\frac{1}{t^2}M_X(t)$$

So when solving for $M_X(t)$ (idea taken from [here](https://www.randomservices.org/random/special/Sine.html)):

$$M_X(t)=-\frac{1}{2t^2}\left[ e^{tx}cos(x) \right]_0^\pi-\frac{1}{t^2}M_X(t)$$

$$M_X(t)\cdot(1+\frac{1}{t^2})=M_X(t)\cdot(\frac{t^2+1}{t^2})=\frac{-1}{2t^2}(e^{\pi t}cos(\pi)-e^{0t}cos(0))=\frac{-1}{2t^2}(-e^{\pi t}-1)=\frac{1}{2t^2}(e^{\pi t}+1)$$

And finally:

$$M_X(t)=\frac{t^2}{t^2+1}\cdot\frac{1}{2t^2}(e^{\pi t}+1)=\frac{e^{\pi t}+1}{2(t^2+1)}$$

Comment: Could you help me understand this section: $-\frac{1}{2t}\left[\frac{1}{t}e^{tx}\cos(x) \right]_0^\pi - \color{red}{\frac{1}{t^2}M_X(t)}$ How do you get this fraction, and make the inference to the next step of $(1+\frac{1}{t^2})$. I have used your link although I could not find the interpretation

Comment: I've edited my answer, is it clearer now?

Comment: That definitely helps clear my misunderstanding for my enquiry on that part. Thank you! Although, could you explain in a little more detail behind the steps below the comment: -"So when solving for $M_X(t)$". I am very unfamiliar with this approach and find it fascinating, though I cannot seem to figure out why we multiply the moment generating function by $1+\frac{1}{t^2}$

Comment: AHA! You add the $M_X(t)$ from the RHS to the LHS and factor the $M_X(t)$ - This approach is so cool!